# Javascript to find URL on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Not sure where to start with this.  I am looking to write some javascript that will be executed as a chrome extension, that will, upon loading of the page, search the page for an url that I know will contain a string of text.  I need to script to return the full URL.  Any thoughts on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that may work for you, based in the small amount of information that your question provides. It uses no 3rd part libraries, only vanilla javascript. it will place each match into an array for you.

HTML

```
<div> <a href="http://some.where/aaa">a</a>
</div>
<div> <a href="http://some.where/bbb">b</a>
    <div> <a href="http://some.where/ccc">c</a>
    </div>
    <div> <a href="http://some.where/ddd">d</a>
        <div> <a href="http://some.where/eee?x=1234">e</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div> <a href="http://some.where/fff">f</a>
</div>
<div> <a href="http://some.where/eee?x=4321">e</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var searchString = "eee";
var hrefs = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function (element) {
    var href = element.href;

    if (href.indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
        hrefs.push(href);
    }
});

console.log(hrefs);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/m9beM/)

Comment: Xotic750, thank you for your assistance.  How would I go about utilizing one of the URLs added to the array using window.location.href?

Comment: You would start by reading some documentation about the javascript Array type from a reliable source like MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2):

some quick psuedo-code from the top of my head..assuming the URL will be in a link (anchor)
this uses jQuery...

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).prop('href').indexOf('something') != -1) {
      do something;
    }
});
```